Visual Studio Installer Project: No option to delete red-underlined files in File System
Today with no changes, Installers built from our Visual Studio Installer Project are failing to install with:
The file '00DD254FD6A48F3F50858FBE393851B0' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file `_EF0346E517198CC1799F225FDE20F75E'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.
Inspecting the File System of the VDPROJ shows many files with red underlines:

I don't see the actual error described and the option to delete the file is grayed out. The file does exist. Readding simply adds a second file to the list without removing the first.
How can the files be deleted or more information be obtained to troubleshoot this?

A fresh install of Visual Studio resolved this
Edit: It happened again and now this, and nothing else can resolve it.
Resolved by spending the effort to move to WiX
